# How can I derived the equation?

Tags: word-problem

The present age of a woman is 30 years older than her daughter. 15 years ago she was twice as old as her daughter. How old is her daughter at present. How old would the woman be 12 years from now. 
Please how can I construct the equation?

Comment: Let $w$ be the present age of the woman and $d$ be the present age of her daughter.  You should get two equations involving $w$ and $d$, which you can solve for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

You can use $w$ for the age of the woman today and $d$ for the age of the daughter today.

So, today, we know a relation between $w$ and $d$. Can you write that equation down?

$15$ years ago, the woman was $(w-15)$ years old; we know that this value is the double of the age of her daughter back then, which was $(d-15)$. Can you write this second equation?

If you were able to write both equations, now you have a system with 2 equations and 2 unknowns that can be solved using different techniques. In this case it seems to me that it will be easy to use the first equation to solve the second.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks for the edit. And I'm sorry for the typos.